# What [QSA,L] in django .htaccess means?

Tags: apache

In this deployment instruction https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/fastcgi/  it says:

```
In your Web root directory, add this to a file named .htaccess:
    .
    .
    .
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

what does `[QSA,L]` means?

Comment: answer almost anything other than the -f. in this link it's -l

Comment: This is not a question about Django or Python, but Apache.